# Can't login to Firebase (Allow Firebase to my Google Account) on Docker Image

Tags: node.js, firebase, docker, firebase-cli

I'm building a **Docker** image with **NodeJs** and **Firebase Tools** for  **a Local Development Environment**.
Since I'm in an non-interactive mode I used

```
firebase login:ci --interactive
```

When running this command on my Dockerfile it retrieves me a token just fine, however when I go to the browser after signing in to my Google Account ***Localhost:9005*** doesn't seem to work

> This site can’t be reached
>   localhost refused to connect.
>   Search Google for localhost 9005
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I also tried

```
firebase login --no-localhost
```

but the console keeps referring me to use login:ci

> Error: Cannot run login in non-interactive mode. See login:ci to generate a token for use in non-interactive environments.

**In short,** I just need to **Allow Firebase** to my environment.**`firebase login --no-localhost` WON'T WORK** (I've already tried it as mentioned in other threads)

Here's my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:carbon
USER    root
RUN     apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

# set user to avoid permission issues
# (see https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1236)
USER    node

RUN     mkdir /home/node/.npm-global
ENV     PATH=/home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
ENV     NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global

RUN     npm install -g firebase-tools

# Logging in to Firebase
# RUN     firebase login --no-localhost
RUN     firebase login:ci --interactive

# Initialising Firebase Project
RUN     firebase init hosting \
&&  firebase init functions \
&&  cd functions/ \
&&  npm i express --save \
&&  cd .. \
&&  ls
```

Check some Screenshots:

[image: Link to Image - #1 step]

[image: Link to Image - #2 step]

[image: Link to Image - #3 step]

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest you move the firebase login step to runtime. By runtime, I mean when the Docker container is running.

So the only FCM related command your Dockerfile should have would be:

```
RUN npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Then, when running your container, map port 9005 in the container to the same port on your host machine like so:

```
docker run \
    -i -t \
    ...
    -p 9005:9005 \
```

(**N.B.** This is assuming the redirect port is fixed to *9005*)

Then you can then run the other commands within the container (using *docker exec*):

```
firebase login
firebase init functions
...
```

(**P.S.** I am sure there would be better approaches for a Production environment, because my answer would only work well for local development)

Answer (score 2):

old question but for anyone trying to login without interacting with the terminal (for example while Dockerizing an emulator), you can login with a token using the `FIREBASE_TOKEN` environment variable.
the token can be obtained by running: `firebase login:ci` and then signing in the automatically-opened browser window. Back in the terminal, you will get a token that you can use later while signing in 'non-interactive' mode by assigning and exporting the `FIREBASE_TOKEN` env. variable to the running container.